# IntelliJ - Integrating Changes to svn Branch

Tags: svn, merge, intellij-idea

I am trying to use an option available in IntelliJ to push the changes from trunk to one of the branch as described here: 
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/integrating-changes-to-branch.html

But it doesnot seem to work. It results in below error, though I have required To & From location pointed to required targets:

"Can not start integration: target directory is not under Subversion control or does not belong to the selected branch."

-- And here, I think local/ working copy should not be considered for merge, as this option is to merge from trunk to some branch.

Also noticed, this options not correctly seem to be working as per the ticket logged in jetbrains:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-45525#comment=27-393692

Let me know if I am missing something here / there exists some easy alternate way of achieving this?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) please ensure that you correctly matched remote folders to local in configure branches. Also, urls should coinside
i.e. if you have copied /trunk/parent into /branches/branch/parent, you should specify
/trunk/parent and /branches/branch/parent
or
/trunk/parent/child and /branches/branch/parent/child
but not
/trunk/parent and /branches/branch/parent/child

2) also, merge in Subversion is always done through local working copy (and in other vcs as far as I know)
merge is 1) Subversion creates patch for 2 urls you pass + parameters (or for url and revisions of it) 2) it applies patch to local working copy, possibly also recording merge information into special properties 3) you commit it to target branch